# Clarifying which ANOVA to use

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss

In my study, all participants underwent a decision task, followed by a training task, followed by a decision task. ALL participants had a response delay on ONE of the decision tasks. This was counterbalanced.

I want to see if the training affects decision making, so I'd need to compare scores before and after training. However, results would be confounded by the response delay. SO, I'll compare the before-training results of participants who didn't have a response delay before training, to the after training results of participants who didn't have a response delay after training.

I also want to see if response delay affects decision making. So, I'd compare the before training results of participants with response to delay to the before training results of participants without response delay.

When accounting for a control group (before training, no delay) and a combination effect (after training, with delay), I'll have four groups for ANOVA.

Is this a one-way, between factor ANOVA, even though technically some of the participants are in the same group? (Those in the before training, no delay group would also be in the after training, with delay group, for example.) The way I am parsing out results puts them in different groups based on differing analysis of the behavioural intervention, but I'm unsure if this is okay or not.